# joda-time datepicker Android not calulating the correct days

Tags: android, datepicker, jodatime

This is a simple question. does anyone know how to set up a date picker for the joda time. i have a date picker set up which is given in the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html), the method that the tutorial give to get the current date is the calender.get instance when putting the date i get into the joda time i get a weird reading of -20 between 1 march 2012 and 12 march 2012

this is the code i am using

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Date past = new Date(112, 3, 1); // June 20th, 2010
    Date today = new Date(112, mMonth, mDay); // July 24th 
    int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays();
    mDateDisplay.setText(""+days);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date past = new Date(112, 3, 1);
```

That date represents 1st April 2012 - months are 0-based. (Jan = 0, Feb = 1, etc).

I figure that 12th March is 20 days before 1st April, i.e., -20, so that would explain it.

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what it is. i was unaware of the date thing

Comment: Don't worry I've been caught out by that one too, as have many others.